# Итерация в angularjs

Tags: bootstrap, angularjs

Здравствуйте!

Вкратце проблема в следующем: через ng-repeat повторяются блоки. Необходимо, чтобы в блоках при каждом повторении было уникальное поле с именем "name" (т.е. в моем случае `name="имя{{функция счетчика}}"`). Впрочем это можно сделать через итерацию, т.е. написать простенькую функцию в контроллере, но это почему-то не работает.

Вот код:

index.html:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="radioForm">
    <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <p>{{question.ask}}</p>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="question.answer1" name="optionsRadios{{count}}" ng-value="question.answer1">
                {{question.answer1}}
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="question.answer2" name="optionsRadios{{count}}" ng-value="question.answer2">
                {{question.answer2}}
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="question.answer3" name="optionsRadios{{count}}" ng-value="question.answer3">
                {{question.answer3}}
            </label>
        </div>

     <br />
     </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Проверить</button>
</form>
```

Controller.js:

```
angular.module('testpage').controller('TestpageController', ['$scope', '$http',
function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/list/questions')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.questions = data;
            $scope.count = function() {
                var k=0;
                for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
                    k = k + i;
                }
                return k;
                console.log(k);
            };

            console.log(data.length);

        })
        .error(function(err) {
            console.log("err", err);
        });
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас здесь сразу несколько ошибок.

1. В своем варианте вы просто пытаетесь вывести функцию, не выполняя ее. Если даже такое нужно будет сделать, то это будет выглядеть так: `optionsRadios{{ count() }}`.
2. Так делать ни в коем случае нельзя, потому что обращение к функции будет происходить не только при каждой итерации, но и при каждом рендере шаблона. То есть любая переменная шаблона изменилась, ангуляр его перерисовал, попутно увеличив счетчики.
3. Ваша функция count вообще ничего полезного не делает, а лишь хитрым способом выводит data.length, то есть всегда одно и то же число - длину массива.

То, что вы хотите сделать, можно и нужно делать через переменную счетчика $index, то есть `"optionsRadios{{ $index }}"`.

При использовании $index может быть только одна проблема - если вам понадобится несколько подобных блоков на странице. Тогда в каждом из них будут одинаковые имена. В таком случае возможно такое решение с директивой и фабрикой: http://jsfiddle.net/43xx9fq9/

Вкратце: каждый элемент, нуждающийся в уникальном имени, оборачивается соответсвующей директивой, которая с помощью фабрики регистрирует себя, получая уникальный номер.

Comment: расцеловал бы